# Detect when file has finished downloading

Tags: python, shell, download

I am downloading a file from a remote server using

> spawn scp

command inside a shell script, and once it's done downloading I want to send to another user.
So I need a way to detect when the file is done downloading.

Comment: This question does not seem relevant to Python?

Comment: How about `spawn "scp ...; tell other user"`

Comment: @mhawke I am working on a python project, so the reason I added python was so that if there is a way check if a file is done downloading using python then that is also acceptable.

I'm using python's `subprocess.call` to call the shell script

Comment: `spawn` reads the commands to execute from stdin, not from cmd line arguments. Perhaps you should post a bit more of your script. Are you using `spawn` to run a single `scp` command?

Comment: @Nkosana: OK, so it is Python related (couldn't tell from the question). How about using [`scp paramiko`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scp), or maybe [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Until the download completed your shell script will stop at `spawn scp`. Therefore you can add rest of your command to transfer the file below this statement like below:-

```
spawn scp
# Check the downloaded file is available or not here
# if the file available
# just use ftp/ftps/scp command to transfer to your friend's server
# after a successful transfer exit with 0
# for failure exit with 1
```